# How to set limit on input type date on today and day before

Tags: php, html

**Am trying to limit the date to today's date and a day before**

```
<label for="sel1">Select Date:</label>
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" min=? name="date">

</select>
```

Comment: you first need to assign a variable to your date function and then calculate one day less and assign a variable to that, then use it for your min.

Comment: It wouldn't have killed to you have Google'd "date minus one day php".

Answer (score 1):

You can use date time objects and `modify`. This is my personally preferred way (though there are others).

```
<?php 
$min = new DateTime();
$min->modify("-1 days");
$max = new DateTime();
?>

<label for="sel1">Select Date:</label>
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" min=<?=$min->format("Y-m-d")?> max=<?=$max->format("Y-m-d")?> name="date">

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the dates using the min and max attributes on the input. If you want to do this automatically with a bit of php you could try something similar to the following:

```
<?php
$yesterday = new DateTime();
$yesterday->sub(new DateInterval('P1D')); // go back one day
echo $yesterday->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>

<label for="sel1">Select Date:</label>
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" min="<?php echo $yesterday;?>" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" name="date">

</select>
```